# How to exclude particular rows in Mysql Query

Tags: mysql

I have below mentioned two tables:

Table1

```
ID        Part1        key       Unique_1
ARF-11    Aekjh        aer-ert   IYT-15
ARF-12    Aferf        aee-sta   IYT-15
ARF-13    Berfe        aer-ert   IYT-15
ARF-14    Aeret        aty-ert   IYT-16
ARF-15    xrete        ant-ert   IYT-16
ARF-16    srete        ant-ert   IYT-17
```

Table2

```
Key      Value
aer-ert  Some
aee-sta  ALL
aty-ert  Few
ant-ert  Less
```

I want to fetch only those rows where for every `Unique_1` value there should be no value=ALL or (`key!=aee-sta`).

Remove such rows, where for any `Unique_1` value there is Value=ALL.

Required Output:

```
ID        Part1        key       Unique_1  Value
ARF-14    Aeret        aty-ert   IYT-16    Few
ARF-15    xrete        ant-ert   IYT-16    Less
ARF-16    srete        ant-ert   IYT-17    Less
```

Comment: Can you give a sample query of what you've tried. You'll likely want to use a `JOIN` query followed by `WHERE Unique_1 IN ("IYT-16", "IYT-17")` but you'll need to try first and post back here when you're having trouble.

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to understand. Read your question and see how difficult it for other

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.part1, t1.key, t1.unique_1, t2.value FROM table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.unique_1 FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
        ON t1.key = t2.key AND (t2.`value` IN('All') OR t2.`key` IN('aee-sta'))
    ) AS tt
    ON tt.unique_1 != t1.Unique_1  
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.key = t1.key
```

Try this [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8397ae/1)